# Какие есть подходы для оценки времени разработки бэклога из проектов?

Tags: архитектура, agile, проекты

Какие есть подходы для оценки времени разработки бэклога из проектов?

Почему возник вопрос.

1. Нужно оценить стоимость проекта
2. Нужно оценить возврат инвестиций

Проблема.

1. Оценить экспертами из тимлидов (оценка лаптём и фактически бесполезна)
2. Оценить командами (дорого, поскольку даже верхнеуровневая проработка одного проекта может затягиваться на несколько дней, а если проектов десяток)

Comment: Оценить затраты на разработку проекта могут только люди с опытом разработки аналогичных проектов (разработчики) или с опытом оценки аналогичных проектов (аналитики). В любом случае оценка людьми без аналогичного опыта бесполезна.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, в целом так, но всегда есть допуски. И лучше иметь какую-то оценку, чем никакую. Вопрос ещё в том, что считать "аналогичным".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует масса методологий оценки проекта в различных ситуациях, но, в принципе, можно ограничиться способами, изложенными в PMBOK (Стандарте управления проектами, Своде знаний управления проектами и связанными с ними документами).

Имеет смысл предлождить один из методов ниже (они для оценки стоимости, но можно и время работы оценить так - это упрощение метода будет, но принципиально ничего не изменится). При этом надо понимать, что если только это не что-то совсем стандартное (десятое по счету web-расписание с минимальными отклонениями), то первоначальная оценка будет лишь "определением порядка величины" и её отличие от окончательной реальности лежит в диапазоне от -25% до +75%. По мере развития проекта точность увеличивается.

И да, все эти методы будут отличаться по стоимости (усилиям на них), надо найти правильный баланс между возможными потерями из-за неточной оценки и стоимостью самой оценки. Это может быть одним из самых ключевых факторов выбора метода оценки.

Сами методы:

1. Укрупнённая оценка "сверху вниз" (чаще менеджментом) - быстро и грубо.
2. "Снизу вверх" (экспертами или исполнителями и с массой "перезакладов"). Как понимаю, декомпозиция уже выполнена (есть backlog), так что можно попытаться выполнить поэлементную оценку.
3. Оценка "по аналогу" - надо найти схожие проекты для этого,  понять их различия с этим проектом.
4. Параметрические модели оценок - строится упрощённая параметрическая модель, учитываются факторы влияния и т.д. (судя по описанию автора вопроса это будет сложно для данного случая).

Если не  уходить в детали, то оценка тимлидами (метод 2, скорее всего) не будет таким уж "лаптём" (лучше, но не обязательно иметь аналогичный опыт), и всяко будет лучше отсутствия оценок. Вы можете дать оценкам разных тимлидов разные веса в зависимости от их опыта, это повысит точность несколько. Если команда сильная, то можно не ограничиваться только тимлидами, а обсудить всей командой (если говорим про стандартную команду в scrum в 5-9 человек) - точность вырастет. Кроме того, если речь о крупной компании, то можно ПМов запросить проведение оценки или даже руководство (но будет метод 1 или 3, скорее). Можно и найти в интернете тех, кто выполнял схожие проекты и получить их оценки (бесплатно или даже за деньги, если так дешевле, чем самим считать).

Без описания реальной ситуации трудно дать совершенно точный ответ, поэтому ограничусь тем, что выше. В реальности такие вещи голосом обсуждать надо для конкретики и c быстрой обратной связью от спрашивающего для коррекции ответа, если есть желание, можем как-то созвониться (Skype голосом без видео предпочтительно). Опыта оценки именно времени на backlog нет, но с самой оценкой проектов я знаком хорошо на практике (теорию не очень знаю, но вряд ли вопрос тут о ней).

Comment: Вы слишком сильно напираете на отсутствие конкретики по проекту, тогда как вопрос звучит "**Какие есть подходы** для оценки времени разработки бэклога из проектов?" Если этот лишний шум убрать, то ответ будет чётче и полезнее для Базы Знаний (для других посетителей).

Comment: @Kromster, я отвечаю на вопросы конкретных людей в первую очередь. Если у человека 8K+ баллов тут, то я уверен, что он способен провести поиск по интернету по ключу "подходы к оценке стоимости back-log". Поэтому ответ мой дан именно относительно конкретного вопроса с его особенностями. И поэтому я подчеркиваю необходимость конкретики. Другому человеку с другим вопросом я бы ответил по-другому. Переносить же в базу знаний сюда то, что отлично описано в PMBOK, я смысла не вижу.  Впрочем, если автор тоже сообщит мне, что эти комментарии про необходимость конкретики - "лишний шум", то я их уберу.

Comment: Вы путаете личные консультации (у ТС указана почта, есть чат, и прочие методы связи) и публичные вопросы и ответы общего плана направленные на широкую аудиторию.

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо. 1) Что такое TC и где все это указано, например, у вас? (или у меня). 2) Мой ответ подойдёт  широкой аудитории (хотя лучше ей открыть PMBOK), но сфокусирован всё же на конкретном вопросе. Полная аналогия с подавляющим большинством ответов здесь, когда от автора вопроса/кода требуют еще конкретных деталей, сообщая, что без них другого ответа не будет.

Comment: @Kromster, но я убрал из ответа два из трех упоминаний о необходимости конкретики и перенес оставшееся в конец:-)

Comment: ТС - это распространенный слэнг, обозначает ТопикСтартера - автора вопроса. Вы можете посмотреть его профиль, там он указал свой контактный емейл. Следует разделять вопросы практического плана (как завернуть именно этот шуруп именно в такую доску моей Java отверткой) и вопросы более общего плана или теоретические (какие есть методы скрепления досок).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136568/discussion-between--and-kromster).